# Detect screen resolution and modify layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to check whether user's resolution is <1300px or >1300px and if it is <1300px to load layout with horizontal divs and if it is >1300px to load layout with vertical divs.

Template is the same I only need to put one div in horizontal or vertical position depening on resolution.

Since I cannot do it with PHP, I have to do it with javascript, so I would have to use "load" function to load part of my template where is vertical or horizontal div? I'm using Yii framework

Comment: No.  You need to use CSS media queries.

Comment: I'm curious, what do you want to do when it's 1300? You've said what you want for < 1300 and > 1300... ;-)

Comment: put div in different places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS media query for that:

```
// For screen < 1300px
@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
    .foo {
        ...
    }
}

// For screen > 1300px
@media screen and (min-width: 1300px) {
    .foo {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically this sort of thing is in the CSS domain (via [media queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_queries)), not the JavaScript domain.

You *can* use the [`screen` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.screen), though, to get the dimensions of the user's screen:

```
var width = screen.width; // Or screen.availWidth;
```

Answer (score 1):

[In JavaScript you can detect it by:](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech3.shtml)

```
window.screen.availHeight
window.screen.availWidth
```

while in CSS you need to use [media queries](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px)
```